# Make WordPress' default posts go to /blog -- permalinks not working

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

Consider the following post types

1. `Posts` (default in WordPress)
2. `Accessories` (Custom post type)

I want `posts` to go to `/blog`. `Accessories` slug has been defined as `/accessories`.

To achieve this, in `settings` > `permalinks` > and have defined my `custom structure` as `/blog/%postname%/`.

With this, when I go to `/blog/`, I get a 404. However, when I create a post in `posts`, the `permalink` shows up as `/blog/test-title`.

Also, with the `custom structure` set, when I try and go to `/accessories`, it also 404's.

Questions:

1. Why does `/blog` 404? It should use `index.php` as it's template, no?
2. Why does `/accessories` 404 with this change?
3. How do I get `/blog` and `/accessories` working?

Comment: It is a common mistake. I believe it helps: -https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123387/custom-structure-permalinks-error-404

Answer (score 0):

To get this WordPress permalink stuff to work correctly, the underlying apache web server grabs the incoming URL requests and *rewrites* them underneath the covers so they point to `/index.php?something=something`. For this to work, apache must

- have an extension module called `mod_rewrite` enabled,
- be configured to allow rewriting in your WordPress instance, and
- be able to write a file called `.htaccess` in the same folder as your WordPress `index.php`.

You didn't mention what kind of OS your server lives on, so it's difficult to give you specific advice.  You might check [Digital Ocean's fabulous documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-aren-t-my-wordpress-permalinks-working) for help.